# Deleting Pylons/Beaker session on logout

Tags: pylons, beaker, repoze.who

I'm trying to list online users of my Pylons app by analyzing Beaker's sessions directly from the sessionstore (type = sqla in my case). By "online user" I mean "session has been accessed in the last 30 minutes", and it works nicely.
My current problem is that when a user logs out, the session *doesn't* get deleted, so she still results as online... Is there a way to intercept the logout process and remove the session?

I'm using repoze.who FriendlyFormPlugin to handle login/logout.. I tried to subclass it and override identify() or challenge(), but when I try to gain access to the session, I get a `"No object (name: session) has been registered for this thread"`. Am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mister Daniel Holth pointed out the [post-logout](http://code.gustavonarea.net/repoze.who-friendlyform/#post-logout-action) parameter of FriendlyFormPlugin.